# Comparing tree nodes

Tags: java, c#, .net, collections, tree

Suppose we have a simple tree of nodes:

```
Node 1                        0
 |-Node 1.1                   1
 |  |-Node 1.1.1              2
 |     |-Node 1.1.1.1         3
 |     |-Node 1.1.1.2         4
 |-Node 1.2                   5
    |-Node 1.2.1              6

... etc.
```

I need to be able to compare any 2 nodes by their flat position in the tree. The easiest way is to walk the tree and assign each node an index (as shown above in the rightmost column), then compare the indices. However, there are 2 disadvantages:

1. For large trees, calculation of indices may be time consuming and impractical in case we need to compare only 2 nodes of the tree that contains millions of nodes.
2. Once the tree is modified (nodes inserted/removed), indices need to be re-calculated.

Hence, my question: is there a better approach that would allow me to compare tree nodes by their position without the need to compute indices for each node?

Comment: For your flat position you can use in depth graph search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Maintain, at each node, a count of nodes in the subtree. This permits you to skip quickly to the correct position.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What would be the meaning of `Node 1.1.1.2` being less than `Node 1.2`? As has already been mentioned a depth-first search might solve part of your actual problem but I guess that's not the entirety of it.

Comment: "flat position" as in 0-6 as obtained by some walk of the tree? Or you are actually looking for structural match? ( p->{ c,c,X } and p->p->p->X trees would have the same position for X - 4, but completely different structure...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to use a "materialized path" and compare those paths (i.e. the path might be `"1.1.1.2"` etc.). Depending on whether you know how many nodes per level you'd expect you could use fixed size part parts, e.g. `"001.001.001.002"` and then a simple string compare should do the trick.

That way when inserting/deleting a node you'd only have to update the materialized paths for the new node and the affected subtree. When changing node order you'd do the same for all nodes/subtrees whose order has been changed.

Another approach would be to use "nested sets", have a look here for a short tutorial on both: https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-9902

Basically your problem seems to be related to how to map a tree to a database table, i.e. convert a tree structure into a flat list and back.